# Update/Delete Photo using iOS ALAssetsLibrary?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone App needs to be able to update and delete Photos and Videos on the phone. After seeing the new ALAssetLibrary class I was pretty excited, but now that I'm knee deep in it I'm starting to realize that perhaps Photos and Videos can not be manipulated in the ways I expect.

Just to confirm, is there really no way to update or delete Photos and Videos on iOS, or am I just using the wrong APIs?

I was able to have complete control over Contacts even back before iOS4, and I noticed there's a new API for accessing Calendars now too. Will I be able to update and delete Calendars like I can with Contacts, or should I expect it to give me a hard time like Photos are?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to manipulate existing photos or videos using ALAssetsLibrary, the only thing you can do is save a new photo/video to the Camera Roll.

Comment: Presumably, there is no way to do this from any other API as well? Do you have any idea if I will run into this same issue with Calendar events?

Comment: Found my second part answer here; http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=996952

Comment: Can we not save photos in other albums/ or create new albums and save photos in that?

Comment: @NikitaP: I believe they have made saving to other albums available in an IOS version newer than March 2011, yes.

Comment: can i delete the photo using the avassetlibray from my photos library ?