# Create, Delete, and add pictures to albums in the photos app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Haven't seen anything, but I have seen that you can create albums in the iOS 5 photos.app, and I was curious if there is a way to integrate it in my app.

I need to be able to create the album, upload pictures to it, and be able to delete it.

Thanks,
Coulton

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152430/iphone-how-to-create-a-custom-album-and-give-custom-names-to-photos-in-camera

You might want to look at this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the UIImage class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Adds to the camera roll album (camera) or saved photos album (no camera).

Comment: So there is no way to create albums programmatically? Because if you open up the photos app, you can create albums and put pictures in there...

Comment: I don't think so but I would like to be corrected :)  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299412/update-delete-photo-using-ios-alassetslibrary

Comment: Okay, thought they would def include that with the new photos app. Would bring out some awesome new features for photo apps like mine. Oh well, I'll just save it to the camera roll.

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS5 you can programmatically add albums to Photos. See the [ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722).

You can add an album (which is an `ALAssetsGroup`) with:

```
addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:
```

Every `ALAssetsGroup` has a URL associated with it. You'll want to save it:

```
valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyURL
```

You can then use that URL to get an `ALAssetsGroup` object:

```
groupForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:
```

Once you have your `ALAssetsGroup` you can use `addAsset:` method on it to add an image or video.

Notice: all these methods are asynchronous and return immediately. You do the actual work in the blocks you pass to these methods.