# iPhone - How to create a custom album and give custom names to photos in camera roll programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, nsfilemanager

I am developing an iPhone photo application, so i need to create a separate album with a name "My Album" in camera roll and i need to save my UIImageView image with custom name for example "My Image.png" inside the newly created directory.

How can i do this?

Comment: hi.. have you found how to give custom name to images?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a custom album and add an image pretty easy with these lines of code in iOS:

```
// Create the new album.
__block PHObjectPlaceholder *myAlbum;
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:title];
    myAlbum = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection;
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[myAlbum.localIdentifier] options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = fetchResult.firstObject;

        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];

            // add asset
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:assetCollection];
            [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: That only describe how to set custom album name, what for custom image name?

Comment: @Priyal This class can help you if you are looking for Swift 3 version : https://github.com/SagarSDagdu/SDPhotosHelper

Comment: You can create(fetch) album and save images in one time as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306436/1107242).

Answer (score 20):

Since the `AssetsLibrary` is **deprecated**, please use the `Photos` framework instead (iOS 8 and later).

```
// Deprecated!
import AssetsLibrary

// Swift 3.0
let assetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
assetsLibrary.addAssetsGroupAlbum(withName: "NewAlbum", resultBlock: { assetsGroup in
    print(assetsGroup == nil ? "Already created" : "Success")
}, failureBlock: { error in
    print(error)
})
```

You can use the shared **`PHPhotoLibrary`** object to create new photos but you can't give them specific names because you will be working with assets that need to be managed by the *Photos.app*. Each asset has specific properties. You can fetch objects, request changes, asset/thumbnail loading and caching, etc.

To create a **custom album**, please use the [`PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle:`)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetcollectionchangerequest/1619454-creationrequestforassetcollectio).

Brief example:

```
// Swift 3.0
func createPhotoLibraryAlbum(name: String) {
    var albumPlaceholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        // Request creating an album with parameter name
        let createAlbumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: name)
        // Get a placeholder for the new album
        albumPlaceholder = createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            guard let placeholder = albumPlaceholder else {
                fatalError("Album placeholder is nil")
            }

            let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
            guard let album: PHAssetCollection = fetchResult.firstObject else {
                // FetchResult has no PHAssetCollection
                return
            }

            // Saved successfully!
            print(album.assetCollectionType)
        }
        else if let e = error {
            // Save album failed with error
        }
        else {
            // Save album failed with no error
        }
    })
}
```

Don't forget to **`import Photos`** library.

To create a **new photo asset** on that album, please use the [`PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from:`)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624060-creationrequestforasset).

```
// Swift 3.0
func createPhotoOnAlbum(photo: UIImage, album: PHAssetCollection) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        // Request creating an asset from the image
        let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: photo)
        // Request editing the album
        guard let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album) else {
            // Album change request has failed
            return
        }
        // Get a placeholder for the new asset and add it to the album editing request
        guard let photoPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset else {
            // Photo Placeholder is nil
            return
        }
        albumChangeRequest.addAssets([photoPlaceholder] as NSArray)
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if success {
            // Saved successfully!
        }
        else if let e = error {
            // Save photo failed with error
        }
        else {
            // Save photo failed with no error
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:**

We need to request access to be able to use the Photos library:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
     switch status {
     ...
}
```

**As of iOS 10** and above we also need to add entry for access in the target .plist file for "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description":

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to photos is needed to provide app features</string>
```

Comment: It gives error with Swift 3  on line : "guard let album = fetchResult.firstObject as? PhotoAlbum else {
        assert(false, "FetchResult has no PHAssetCollection")
    }"

Error : Use of undeclared type PhotoAlbum.
Can you please suggest the change ?

Comment: @Priyal try adding `typealias PhotoAlbum = PHAsset`.

Comment: @Priyal Yes, sorry. I mean `typealias PhotoAlbum = PHAssetCollection`. Thanks for you edit.

Comment: could you save an image to custom album using swift 3.?

Comment: @Priyal You need to use `creationRequestForAsset(from:)` to save a new photo and use the `placeholderForCreatedAsset` of that photo to relate with that album. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I am able to add only a single image, When I try to fetch already created album and then add image to it, it gives me error.

Comment: @Priyal please go to the discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132769/discussion-between-priyal-and-ricardopereira

Comment: seems you don't use localIdentifiers, you can create duplicate album with your function

Comment: @user25 No, I don't check if a album exist. It will create a duplicate album. You can check if an album already exist by using `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType` with a NSPredicate like  `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .AlbumRegular, options: fetchOptions)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, from your answer `let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)` I guess we can use it to detect if album with such `localIdentifier` exists, I guess I have to save `localIdentifier` as string in my app prefs when creating album and then use it to check if album exists

Comment: @user25 Well, if you handle everything locally, it sounds good. But, have in mind that, if the user uses iCloud and if he/she changes his/hers iPhone, then things will start to brake because the `localIdentifier` is pointing to a local album that doesn't exist.

Comment: @ricardopereira in my app I check if album with such `localIdentifier` exists, if not then it creates a new album and save `localIdentifier` of new album to Prefs, in any case we will get duplicated albums on the other device that syncs data and has the same app

Answer (score 8):

Create a new album:

```
/// Create album with given title
/// - Parameters:
///   - title: the title
///   - completionHandler: the completion handler
func createAlbum(withTitle title: String, completionHandler: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var placeholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?
        
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let createAlbumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: title)
            placeholder = createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        }, completionHandler: { (created, error) in
            var album: PHAssetCollection?
            if created {
                let collectionFetchResult = placeholder.map { PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [$0.localIdentifier], options: nil) }
                album = collectionFetchResult?.firstObject
            }
            
            completionHandler(album)
        })
    }
}
```

Get an album with with a specified name:

```
/// Get album with given title
/// - Parameters:
///   - title: the title
///   - completionHandler: the completion handler
func getAlbum(title: String, completionHandler: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", title)
        let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
        
        if let album = collections.firstObject {
            completionHandler(album)
        } else {
            self?.createAlbum(withTitle: title, completionHandler: { (album) in
                completionHandler(album)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And save a photo to a Photos album:

```
func save(photo: UIImage, toAlbum titled: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ()) {
    getAlbum(title: titled) { (album) in
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: photo)
                let assets = assetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    .map { [$0] as NSArray } ?? NSArray()
                let albumChangeRequest = album.flatMap { PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: $0) }
                albumChangeRequest?.addAssets(assets)
            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                completionHandler(success, error)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you sort the new albums created programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

It was working from since iOS 5.0.
Please import AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h

```
ALAssetsLibrary* libraryFolder = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[libraryFolder addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:@"My Album" resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) 
{
    NSLog(@"Adding Folder:'My Album', success: %s", group.editable ? "Success" : "Already created: Not Success");
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Adding on Folder");
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try My below Method for Create Album for iOS 7 and iOS 8

```
#define PHOTO_ALBUM_NAME @"AlbumName Videos"
-(void)createAlbum{

// PHPhotoLibrary_class will only be non-nil on iOS 8.x.x
Class PHPhotoLibrary_class = NSClassFromString(@"PHPhotoLibrary");

if (PHPhotoLibrary_class) {


    // iOS 8..x. . code that has to be called dynamically at runtime and will not link on iOS 7.x.x ...

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:PHOTO_ALBUM_NAME];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating album: %@", error);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Created");
        }
    }];
}else{
    [self.library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:PHOTO_ALBUM_NAME resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
        NSLog(@"adding album:'Compressed Videos', success: %s", group.editable ? "YES" : "NO");

        if (group.editable == NO) {
        }

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error adding album");
    }];
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
/// Save images or videos（保存图片或视频）(kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeMovie)
/// Add to album if specified album name, and create album if needed
/// @params mediaArray UIImage, fileURL for a image or video
+ (void)_saveMediaArray:(NSArray *)mediaArray
                options:(LAImageSaverOptions *)options
             completion:(void (^)(NSError * _Nullable err))completion
{
    NSInteger __block count = 0;

    [PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary performChanges:^{

        // Create album if needed
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = nil;
        NSMutableArray<PHObjectPlaceholder *> *assetChangeRequestPlaceholders = nil;
        if (options.targetAlbumName.length > 0) {
            assetChangeRequestPlaceholders = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:mediaArray.count];

            PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.new;
            //fetchOptions.includeAssetSourceTypes = PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary;
            fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localizedTitle = %@", options.targetAlbumName]; // 不能用 block 形式的 predicate
            PHAssetCollection * assetCollection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
            if (nil == assetCollection) {
                assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:options.targetAlbumName];
            } else {
                assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:assetCollection];
            }
         }

        // Save images
        for (id item in mediaArray) {
            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = nil;
            // image object
            if ([item isKindOfClass:UIImage.class]) {
                UIImage *image = (UIImage *)item;
                assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
                [assetChangeRequestPlaceholders addObject:assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset];
                ++count;
                continue;
            }

            // file url for image or movie
            NSURL *fileURL = (NSURL *)item;
            if ([item isKindOfClass:NSURL.class] && fileURL.isFileURL) {
                NSString *extension = fileURL.pathExtension;
                if (extension.length == 0) {
                    NSLog(@"illegal fileURL(no path extension): %@", fileURL);
                    continue; // illegal file url
                }
                CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
                BOOL isImage = false;
                BOOL isVideo = false;
                if (nil != uti && CFStringGetLength(uti) > 0) {
                    isImage = UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeImage);
                    isVideo = UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeMovie); // kUTTypeVideo, kUTTypeAudiovisualContent
                }
                if (isImage) {
                    assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:fileURL];
                    [assetChangeRequestPlaceholders addObject:assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset];
                    ++count;
                } if (isVideo) {
                    assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:fileURL];
                    [assetChangeRequestPlaceholders addObject:assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset];
                    ++count;
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"illegal fileURL(neither image nor movie): %@", fileURL);
                    continue; // illegal file url
                }
            }
        }

        // add to album if needed
        [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:assetChangeRequestPlaceholders];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        // not in main thread 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(error);
        });
    }];
}
```

By the way, you can do more about `LAImageSaverOptions`

```c
@interface LAImageSaverOptions : NSObject

/// to show alert controller on the hostVC
@property(nonatomic, weak, null_resettable) UIViewController *hostVC;


/// total progress
@property (nonatomic, strong, null_resettable) NSProgress *progress;

// album name for saving images
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSString *targetAlbumName;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save image with custom name to sandbox first,and then save it to album,it work to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer