# Is it possible to save an image ONLY to a custom album in iOS6?

Tags: ios, uiimage, directory, avcapturesession, alassetslibrary

I want to save a image captured with `AVCaptureStillimageOutput` and I'm trying to save it using this code :

```
[self.library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image metadata:nil completionBlock:nil]:
```

it's by default saving to PhotoRoll and there is no option to change album.

I found an older guide o how to save image to album using this code:

```
[self.library saveImage:img toAlbum:albumName withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

but it seems to be `deprecated`... Is it possible to make it nondeprecated because i think that this method is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Custom albums only hold shortcuts to the images. All images are stored in the main album (`Camera Roll`), so when adding an image, it'll first need to be added to the main album (can't be saved only in the custom album).

Comment: Thats what I feared. So there is no way at all to save it only in a custom album? is it maybe possible to create a new PhotoRoll?

Comment: That's not possible through the `Photos` app either, so there's probably no way, even if using private apis.

Answer (score 1):

All photos go to the SavedPhotos. Once you saved it there you can use the library method
**addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:**

and then the ALAssetsGroup method
**addAsset:**

Please see this answer for more detail:
[Create, Delete, and add pictures to albums in the photos app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989829/create-delete-and-add-pictures-to-albums-in-the-photos-app)